# Prevenção Session Hijacking

Tags: php, segurança, session

Sei que para prevenir esse tipo de ataque devemos usar session_regenerate_id(), principalmente antes de logar. A minha dúvida é se devo apagar a sessão anterior  passando um true como parâmetro? Entendo que o melhor seria deletar a sessão anterior, mas todos os exemplos que vejo não fazem. Qual seria o correto, o mais seguro?

Comment: Ve esta resposta, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6483097/587811

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar quero afirmar que na segurança o problema nunca é final. Dito isto e sem falar sobre outros temas relacionados com as sessões e respondendo ao caso específico  do **Session Hijacking**, dizer o seguinte:

1. o `session_regenerated_id()` por uma questão de facilidade e ou manutenção deve ser efectuado após a correta validação de credenciais. No entanto já vi aplicações em que este é realizado a cada 30 minutos e em casos extremos o que considero uma paranóia a cada **request**. No login para a maioria dos projetos... é suficiente! Não resolve mas dificulta!
2. Antes do `session_regenerated_id()` é obrigatório chamar `session_destroy()` e porque não o `session_unset()`... o que responde claramente à pergunta.
3. Utilizar alguns campos na sessão para validar a conexão também é importante, como por exemplo o `HTTP_USER_AGENT` ou outros. Também passíveis de manipulação mas mais uma vez... Não resolve mas dificulta!
4. Se o Hijacking da sessão é um problema e dependendo do projecto o SSL responde a este problema. Mais uma vez não resolve totalmente pois existe quem afirme que consegue "dar a volta" ao https mas... Dificulta e muito.
5. Muito útil também um mecanismo de `TOKEN` gravado na sessão para cada `request` seguido de políticas elaboradas para autorizações de processos.

Enfim a lista não acaba pois as soluções podem ser muitas e tinha mais algumas, no entanto um estudo sobre a matéria e a constante monitorização do acompanhamento sobre o processo aplicado é também um excelente complemento à solução.

Nas aplicações que eu crio coloco sempre disponível ao utilizador uma página onde o mesmo pode observar as sessões abertas e ativas e as já expiradas... o que torna o utilizador mais informado e preocupado, minimizando o problema.

Dizer ainda que as sessões do PHP são ficheiro guardados no servidor e isto pode causar alguma entropia ao servidor dependendo do número de acessos colocando o mesmo vulnerável a outro tipo de ataques, mas depende claro do tipo de projeto.