# Trabalhar com session sem cookies para prevenir roubo de sessão

Tags: php, segurança, session, cookies

Quando a sessão é iniciada, ela cria um cookie com *PHPSESSID*, tornando o ID público. Sabendo-se que para prevenir o sequestro de sessão o melhor é esconder o ID da sessão de outros usuários, então *PHPSESSID* se torna um ponto de partida para um ataque. Pode-se recorrer à `session.name` e `session.hash_function`, mas mesmo assim um cookie com um ID é fácil de ser encontrado.

Por exemplo, se eu criar uma `session['nome'] = Fulano de tal` para um usuário chamado *Fulano*, teóricamente, somente ele terá acesso à session. O problema é que se *Joãozinho* alterar o *PHPSESSID* com o valor do *Fulano*, ele terá acesso às sessions criadas. Cookie *PHPSESSID* são suscetíveis ao mau uso de terceiros, ou até uma máquina infectada.

Estou tentando fazer uso de sessions **sem** a criação de cookies, tentei `session.use_cookies = 0` mas todos acessos geram uma nova ID e as sessões que foram salvas são perdidas.

Realmente gostaria de usar as sessions 100% fora do alcance do cliente. Pensei em definir `session.use_cookies = 0` para não fazer uso de cookies por sessão, e usar `session_save_path`, para gerenciar as sessões de usuário, para poder implementar mais verificações.

---

- Há alguma forma no PHP de trabalhar com sessões sem a necessidade de criação de cookie?
- Levando em conta que o cookie é alocado no cliente, seria dele - **e só dele** - a responsabilidade em não permitir que seja público, ou seja, alguém em uma máquina pública deve fazer o logout, ou o usuário usando um computador pessoal deve mantê-la livre de infecções que possam rastrear suas IDs. Essa questão eu tive como base o facebook, onde entrei em uma outra conta alterando os cookies. Era minha outra conta antiga do facebook, não há temores.

Comment: Já pensou em comparar o IP remoto e o user agent, e em caso de inconsistência, destruir a session?

Comment: +1 Muito boa pergunta.

Comment: @Jader, mas se eu guardar em cookie ele pode ser clonado, e se guardar em session pode comparar com a 'roubada'. Ou será que entendi errado?

Comment: Você guarda do IP e o user agent na session, e compara com as variaveis $_SERVER na proxima requisição...

Comment: @Jader, bem interessante, $_SERVER tem algumas variáveis não confiáveis. O próprio IP não é 100%. `user agent` até poderia servir como um SALT.

Comment: Certamente, mas é melhor que nada... Usando várias verificações em conjunto pode ficar bem seguro... E num contexto geral da sua pergunta me parece que você esta confundindo sequestrar a session, com sequestrar um cookie contendo login e senha, e neste caso uma nova session logada é criada...

Comment: Alterar o cookie PHPSESSID, de imediato permite acesso às sessões. Posso fazer verificações mais a fundo dentro do sistema, mas queria saber uma forma de criar as sessões sem a necessidade do cookie para gerenciar o ID.

Comment: O cookie serve apenas para ocultar o session id da URL... Alterar o cookie seria o mesmo que alterar diretamente na URL...

Comment: Sim, e essa é a recomendação para não usar ID como parâmetro na URL. E usar um cookie para isso pra mim é trocar 6 por meia dúzia :)

Comment: Entenda que se você não passar o session id por cookie, será obrigado a passar pela URL... Então uma verificação em cada requisição se ainda é o mesmo cliente é obrigatória em qualquer caso...

Comment: Relacionadas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26610/como-funciona-a-sess%C3%A3o-em-navegadores-web?rq=1, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33740/preven%C3%A7%C3%A3o-session-hijacking?rq=1 (duplicata?)

Comment: Não acho que seja duplicata, minha intenção era uma forma de trabalhar com session sem cookie, sem me aprofundar em Hijacking. O roubo de sessão foi uma forma de mostrar o ID no cookie - o que gostaria de evitar.

Comment: @Papacharlie o controlo de sessões no Php vem com o identificador que o browser guarda... O processo é esse. Deixa para o lado do servidor o controlo da sessão e todas as suas variáveis. Hijacking, para mim a melhor defesa é o SSL. Lê a minha resposta no link que o bfavaretto coloca.

Comment: @chambelix. Eu pretendia cuidar dos roubos de sessão justamenter tendo a base sessão sem cookie. Por isso queria saber se era possível o PHP dar essa "forçinha". Pelo visto vai ser na unha mesmo - vou garimpar todas as respostas. Mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: @Papacharlie Olha...se te ajudar... Acabei de desenvolver para um sistema de identidades.. Controlo de sessão escalável em multi servidor... Conteudo persistente em base de dados e volátil em memcached. Forço o SSL mas não deixo de implementar verificacoes http_User_agent entre outros. Não dispensei um sistema de tokens, renovando o id em certos pontos do serviço. Em conclusão na unha mesmo. Cumprimentos

Comment: @chambelix, legal. Vai disponibilizar em algum lugar?

Comment: @Papacharlie é um trabalho para o qual fui contratado... Mas estou disponível se você precisar de alguma ajuda com alguma orientação com o seu codigo numa solução pois apesar da implementação a monitorização é uma constante... Pelo que temos de ter sempre os nossos conhecimentos updated... Cumprimentos

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Há alguma forma no PHP de trabalhar com sessões sem a necessidade de criação de cookie?

Sim, é possível se trabalhar sem alocar o id da sua sessão em um cookie. Porém, devido o HTTP ser stateless (cada requisição ser independente da outra), essa id deve ser repassada de alguma forma, e essa segunda maneira seria via a URL.

Extraído da [documentação do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.session.php):

> Um visitante acessando o seu web site ganha um identificador único, o
> assim chamado id de sessão. Este é salvo em um cookie do lado do
> usuário ou propagado via URL.

Essa configuração é possível a partir da configuração do [`session.cookie_httponly`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly)

---

> Levando em conta que o cookie é alocado no cliente, seria
> dele - e só dele - a responsabilidade em não permitir que seja
> público, ou seja, alguém em uma máquina pública deve fazer o logout,
> ou o usuário usando um computador pessoal deve mantê-la livre de
> infecções que possam rastrear suas IDs. Essa questão eu tive como base
> o facebook, onde entrei em uma outra conta alterando os cookies. Era
> minha outra conta antiga do facebook, não há temores.

Basicamente sim. O que você pode fazer para minimizar esse risco de sequestro da session é tomar algumas ações no lado do servidor para inviabilizar o uso não autorizado desse cookie.

Algumas ações como regenerar o id da sessão com [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-regenerate-id.php) ou solicitar uma nova autenticação tornam o sequestro do cookie simplesmente inviáveis.

Alguns artigos (em inglês) que podem auxiliar na implementação da segurança da sua aplicação

[Preventing Session Hijacking when using PHP](http://www.rtcx.net/preventing-session-hijacking-using-php/)

[Stopping Session Hijacking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24139/stopping-session-hijacking)

[Cookie Theft/Session Hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Cookie_Theft/Session_Hijacking)

Comment: Aqui tem duas respostas que podem complementar sua resposta: 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php/3604#3604 e 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33664/lembrar-usu%C3%A1rio-com-seguran%C3%A7a/33684#33684

Comment: É estranho as sessions serem recomendadas para dados sensíveis, e depender do cookie para gerenciar o ID. O PHP poderia usar o mecanismo para identificar a sessão no cookie e/ou no path usando `session_save_path`.

Comment: @PapaCharlie acredito que esse comportamento esteja mais ligado a natureza do HTTP em não permitir guardar o estado entre as requisições. No .net temos o [mesmo comportamento](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que o php, armazenando o id da sessão em cookies.

Answer (score 11):

Me parece que você está buscando algo impossível. Antes de responder à sua pergunta, deixe-me fazer uma outra pergunta semelhante:

> Quando se registra em um site se cria um nome de usuário e senha. Sabendo-se que para prevenir o roubo da conta é melhor não compartilhar sua senha com outros usuários, então o campo `password` se torna um ponto de partida para um ataque. Se Alice cria uma senha, teoricamente somente ela terá acesso à sua conta, o problema é se Bob fizer login com o *username* e *password* de Alice. Senhas são suscetíveis ao mau uso de terceiros, ou até uma máquina infectada (*keylogger*, por exemplo).
>
> Há alguma forma de se gerenciar contas de usuários sem a necessidade do uso de senhas?

Colocado dessa forma, fica evidente (espero!) que não há muito o que fazer... Espera-se da aplicação que use senhas corretamente (use SSL, não as envie por GET, limpe-as após o uso), espera-se do *browser* que as manipule corretamente (não as salve em arquivo, esconda os caracteres digitados num campo `password`) e espera-se que o computador/dispositivo esteja livre de infecções (não possua um *keylogger*, não intercepte a senha no browser antes mesmo dela ser criptografada, etc). E é claro, espera-se que o usuário não compartilhe sua senha com terceiros.

Esses riscos sempre estarão presentes ao se utilizar senhas. Você *até pode* optar por não usá-las, mas aí você teria que **arcar com os custos** de não fazê-lo (ex.: usar um módulo de hardware para autenticar usuários - que pode ser roubado - usar um gerador de códigos HOTP/TOTP - idem - usar um certificado digital no lado cliente - ibidem) - sendo o principal deles a inconveniência aos usuários. Essa opção deve se pautar numa análise de custo-benefício, não numa busca por eliminar riscos a qualquer custo (por que então não exigir que os usuários se desloquem fisicamente até sua empresa para usar seu sistema, sob suas vistas?).

Um cookie - em especial um que seja `HttpOnly` (i.e. inacessível via JavaScript) além é claro de `Secure` (só é transmitido via HTTPS) - é a maneira mais segura e conveniente que uma aplicação web comum possui para reautenticar o usuário (i.e. saber que a requisição Y foi enviada pelo mesmo usuário que antes lhe enviou a requisição X - esta contendo seu nome de usuário e senha). Pode-se é claro variar um pouco o *tradeoff* citado, por exemplo:

- Colocando um token secreto (i.e. o ID da sessão) na própria URL, como [apontado na resposta do gmsantos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36689/215). As desvantagens são:

  1. A URL pode ser posta em cache, aumentando a exposição desse ID;
  2. Se o usuário abrir o site em uma outra aba, ele não estará necessariamente autenticado (se ele entrou diretamente, sem seguir um link contendo esse ID).
- Mantendo-se o ID da sessão em memória somente; isso exigiria uma aplicação "de única página" onde toda a comunicação com o servidor é feita via Ajax, e o ID da sessão fica numa variável JavaScript - enviada junto aos parâmetros POST a cada requisição. Desvantagens:

  1. Toda comunicação teria que se dar via POST, para evitar que o ID acabe na URL como no caso acima;
  2. O uso ficaria restrito a uma única aba do navegador, a menos que se implementasse a comunicação entre diferentes abas (complicado, e ainda traz riscos adicionais);
  3. Diminui-se o risco do ID ir parar em arquivo, mas torna-o mais suscetível a XSS.
- Guardando o ID da sessão no `SessionStorage`; semelhante aos dois casos acima (pois esse ID ainda teria de ser enviado de volta ao servidor de alguma maneira), e ainda possui o risco dos dados irem parar em arquivo de qualquer forma (se o browser travar, posteriormente um outro usuário poderia "restaurar a sessão" - já iniciando autenticado como o usuário original).
- Reautenticando o usuário a cada requisição! Assim você não precisa de ID da sessão (nem mesmo de uma sessão!), só exija que o usuário entre com sua senha de novo, e de novo, e de novo...

Etc. Pode-se pensar em outras maneiras, mas na minha visão nenhuma delas seria significativamente diferente do uso de cookies, pois:

1. Se a máquina estiver infectada, já era! Nada a menos que um módulo de hardware irá te proteger nesse caso, e ainda assim limitado a alguns poucos cenários;
2. Se a solução envolver dados salvos em arquivo, qualquer usuário com root poderá acessá-los (assim como um usuário com root pode roubar o *cookie jar* do browser);
3. Um browser "honesto" honra a política de mesma origem (i.e. nenhuma outra origem - esquema, domínio e porta - pode acessar esses cookies), não expõe indevidamente um cookie `HttpOnly` ao JavaScript, nem envia indevidamente um cookie `Secure` sem a devida proteção. Um "browser desonesto" (digamos, um usuário fazendo acesso direto via curl por exemplo) por outro lado poderia fazer mau uso de todos os dados, independentemente de como eles estão armazenados.

Concluindo então, minha posição é de que trabalhar sem cookies não é o melhor caminho para se garantir a segurança de sua aplicação. Em vez disso, procure diminuir a "janela de oportunidade" para o sequestro de sessão (via `session_regenerate_id`, como já sugerido, e/ou invalidando a sessão após X minutos de inatividade) e talvez aumente o requisito para realizar ações críticas no sistema (ex.: para trocar de senha, peça a senha original *de novo*, mesmo que a sessão seja válida). Tome os cuidados cabíveis, mas não se preocupe demais com os riscos inerentes ao uso de cookies - pois estes seriam os mesmos em toda exceto pela mais segura (e cara) das soluções.

Comment: Entendi seu exemplo claramente, mas até os dias de hoje as pessoas acreditam que senha *123456* é secreta. Por isso levantei a questão da responsabilidade e "isenção" dela pelo mau uso dos dados. De fato, parece que trabalhar sem cookies sem a ajuda da linguagem não vale o sacrifício, o CxB aparentemente não compensa. Obrigado, clareou alguns pontos.