# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de armazenar variáveis de sessão no banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, segurança, cookies

A partir do Rails 4.0, foi eliminado o *ActiveRecord Session Store*, que guardava variáveis de sessão no banco de dados, por "problemas de desempenho." Porém a funcionalidade continua funcionando através de uma *gem*. Hoje o Rails utiliza o *Cookie Session Store*.

> **ActiveRecord session store** - The ActiveRecord session store is extracted to a separate gem. Storing sessions in SQL is costly. Instead, use cookie sessions, memcache sessions, or a custom session store.
>
> Fonte: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html

Traduzido:

> **ActiveRecord session store** - O *ActiveRecord session store* foi transferido para uma gem separada. Armazenar sessões no banco de dados é custoso [em termos de desempenho]. Ao invés disso, use sessões baseadas em cookies, memcache sessions, ou uma *session store* personalizada.

- Gem: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store
- Commit em rails/rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0ffe19056c8e8b2f9ae9d487b896cad2ce9387ad

Apesar disso, encontro referências na web dizendo que ainda é recomendado o seu uso (para evitar *session hijacking*, por exemplo). O próprio guia do Rails sobre segurança (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) parece sugerir isso, apesar de não citar nominalmente a *gem*.

Afinal, é realmente vantagem usar o banco de dados para guardar variáveis de sessão, como o *id* do usuário logado, etc? O custo de desempenho chega a ser perceptível?

Comment: Relacionado com Session Hijacking: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36687/4751

Answer (score 2):

Não sou um especialista em Web, mas acredito que posso contribuir com a questão.

## Sessões no banco de dados

### Vantagens

- **Facil escalabilidade**
  Considerando que não seja uma aplicação que utilize replicação da base de dados, é mais simples armazenar os dados em um recurso que seja compartilhado entre os servidores.
- **Facilidade de implementação** Controlar uma sessão via banco gera uma implementação mais simples, baseada em queries e comandos sql, coisa que a maioria dos desenvolvedores conhece bom

### Desvantangens

- **Lentidão** Sendo um recurso compartilhado, se a quantidade de leituras e gravações for muito grande, a "vantagem" de ser um recurso compartilhado pode causar lentidão em todos os servidores por excesso de carga na base de dados
- **Violação de camadas** Tecnicamente, o banco de dados é uma camada de persistência, e não um recurso meio ou de armazenamento temporário. Sendo assim, locais que não precisariam serializar seu acesso, solicitando dados à base, passam a exigir mesmo onde não existe a necessidade

### Alternativas

**Reddis**: é um servidor de dados em memória, distribuído com opcional de persistência com ótima velocidade, open source e mantido pela Pivotal Software
<sup>**Fonte**: Wikipedia</sup>

**Memcached**: Sistema de cache distribuído de objetos em memória de alta performance, gratuito e de código aberto.
<sup>Fonte: http://memcached.org/</sup>

Não utilizar a sessão, mas sim manter na app cliente os dados e utilizar autenticação por basic, Digest ou token authentication

Comment: você não se contradis noo fácil escalabilidade e lentidão quando houver muitas gravações e leituras?

Answer (score 0):

O principal uso para sessão em bd é quando você quer compartilhar a sessão entre mais de um aplicativo.

Também é possivel utilizar para armazenar mais dados do que os cookies permiterm (4k)

Quanto a performance, é perceptível se for medido em ferramentas como newrelic, para o usuário final depende muito do que a aplicação faz.

Se por qualquer motivo você precisar armazenar sessões que não em cookies, use memcached.

Segue um exemplo de como fazê-lo: https://github.com/mperham/dalli#usage-with-rails-3x-and-4x