# O que guardar em uma sessão de login?

Tags: php, mysql, segurança, session, login

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login em PHP e MySQL para um painel de administração, e já vi muitos sistemas "seguros" de login onde eles armazenam na sessão o login do usuário ou a senha, isso quando não são ambos ou até todos os dados do usuário logado.

Já construí sistemas de login antes, e foi basicamente desta forma, mas preciso de algo mais seguro, não posso guardar a informações de login do usuário na sessão.

Alguma dica? ideia?

Comment: Guardar o ID do usuário é suficiente.

Comment: Confere o seguinte no console do browser `console.log(StackExchange.options.user)`

Comment: @bfavaretto, se eu guardar algo além do ID, é ruim?

Comment: @Patrick só compensa guardar coisa que não tem importância ser acessada pelo cliente (como preferências de navegação, etc.). O resto é melhor que fique na sessão mesmo, assim o navegador do cliente não tem como acessar os dados. Se quiser deixar a sessão um pouco mais robusta, pode associar a ela o IP atual do usuário por exemplo (cuidado com efeitos colaterais, entretanto).

Comment: Pode até salvar senha em cookie ou session desde que seja criptografado. A vantagem de salvar esses dados em cookie,  em client ou server, é poupar recursos de conexão com banco de dados em todas as requisições que exigirem e identificação e autenticação.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Para clarificar

Qualquer sistema de login implementado em PHP ou seja em que linguagem for que guarda na sessão os dados de login, em particular a password ou a combinação de password + nome de utilizador, é um sistema inseguro.

---

## A segurança dos cookies de sessão

Os cookies de sessão, [`$_SESSION`](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php), cujos mesmos são gerados e guardados no servidor podem ser acedidos por terceiros, apesar de requerer algum trabalho, pelo que, quaisquer dados a guardar na sessão devem ser dados não comprometedores e com o intuito de otimizar o código e/ou reduzir o numero de consultas à base de dados.

PHP Security Consortium tem um [guia online sobre segurança](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/) onde salienta dois problemas com a sessão, embora os mesmos possam ser ultrapassados com o devido cuidado por parte do programador:

- [**Session Fixation**](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html#4.1)

  > Fixation is the simplest method of obtaining a valid session identifier. While it's not very difficult to defend against, if your session mechanism consists of nothing more than [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), you are vulnerable.

  que traduzido:

  > Fixação é o método mais simples de obter um identificador de sessão válido. Embora não seja muito difícil de defender, se o seu mecanismo de sessão consiste em nada mais do que [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), você está vulnerável.
- **[Session Hijacking](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html#4.2)**

  > Arguably the most common session attack, session hijacking refers to all attacks that attempt to gain access to another user's session.
  >
  > As with session fixation, if your session mechanism only consists of `session_start()`, you are vulnerable, although the exploit isn't as simple.

  Que traduzido:

  > Provavelmente o ataque mais comum à sessão, o sequestro de sessão refere-se a todos os ataques onde se tenta ganhar acesso a sessão de outro usuário.
  >
  > Tal como acontece com fixação de sessão, se o seu mecanismo de sessão consiste apenas de `session_start()`, você está vulnerável, embora a tentativa com sucesso não seja tão simples.

### Limitação da Sessão

A sessão tem um limite no que respeita aos dados armazenados que é imposto pelo tamanho [máximo do ficheiro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) no sistema operativo. Não obstante, existe também o limite da memória imposto pela diretiva [`memory_limit`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) que limita a quantidade de memória que um script de PHP pode consumir no servidor.

Dos dois, o que for mais baixo será o espaço máximo que a sessão pode ocupar.

### Sessão vs Base-de-dados

A sessão quando criada gera um ID único por visitante, ID esse que nos permite identificar a pessoa de forma distinta em relação às outras. Esse ID guardado numa tabela de login na base de dados junto com a restante informação que precisamos para a sessão do utilizador é de fato uma das formas mais seguras de manter o sistema de login do website/aplicação.

Onde a segurança é um fator mais critico do que aquilo que habitualmente já o é, podemos ver as coisas desta maneira: Em teoria, é mais facil chegar aos dados em sessão do que chegar aos dados na base de dados dado a mesma estar por trás de mais passwords de acesso.

### O que guardar na sessão

Guardar dados na sessão bem como chegarmos a utilizar ou não a sessão é algo que vai depender da informação a gerir. Por norma a sessão torna-se util para guardar informação do tipo:

- Erros dum formulário;
- Mensagens ao utilizador;
- Endereços para redirecionamento após determinada ação.

Ou seja, a sessão dá-nos a flexibilidade de guardar dados de forma persistente e facilmente acessíveis. A sessão não é propriamente uma base de dados para armazenar informação critica ou comprometedora.

---

**Sumário**

Base de dados para guardar os dados do utilizador com login realizado é o caminho a seguir.

O uso da sessão é particularmente útil para guardar informação de auxilio à navegação e interação com o utilizador.

Dados comprometedores devem ficar em base de dados, nunca em sessão.

Login + Password nunca guardar na sessão e a password nunca guardar sem estar encriptada.

Comment: a sua resposta está muito didática..... Gostei. Para melhorar adicione que dados de sessão persistentes a melhor forma é em base de dados e que em sistemas com muitos acessos é importante adicionar ao mecanismo uma cache do tipo "memcached" para que a base de dados não entre colapso melhorando também a capacidade de resposta. Parabéns pela resposta.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que o cookie está na máquina do visitante e está disponível facilmente e qualquer pessoa pode editá-lo.
Imagine a minha id é "Peter". Eu estou em seu site, com login. Vou dar uma olhdada no Cookie e ver lá dentro "id = Peter". 
Eu vou perguntar um colega qual e seu id, ele vai me dizer que é (por exemplo)  "maximo". Vou colocar um cookie com "id = maximo" e eu poderia me conector como ele.
Não é muito seguro ...

Isto requer que o cookie contém informações suficientes para que você saiba quem está conectado (não só o seu id, mas também outras informações que você pode misturar para verificar se eles são corretas, por exemplo id visitante, a sua idade, o seu CEP etc ...) e também que o cookie é criptografada.

A dificuldade é que você não pode ter uma criptografia assimétrica, porque você vai ter que ler o cookie para levar informações.
Portanto, você deve determinar o que precisa armazenar, preparar os dados como uma string, criptografar a string e colocar no cookie.
Após a leitura, você vai ter que decifrar o cookie e remover as "string" e verificar a integridade. Você pode, por exemplo criptografar de acordo com a data de apresentação do Cookie, a localização do visitante etc ... Então, se alguém consegui "quebrar" o cookie, ele também vai dever saber a localização geográfica de que ele quer usurpar identidade, que rapidamente se torna complicado.

Aqui está uma pequena classe de criptografia que pode ajudá-lo. Eu, obviamente, não pode mostrar-lhe o caminho completo que eu uso para criptografar meus cookies.

```
 class Chiffrement
{
// Cipher:
// cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192
//  saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish
// enigma rc2 tripledes 

// Modes:
// cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream 

private static $cipher  = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;  // Cipher

private static $mode    = 'cbc';  // Mode (blocoss)

public static function crypt($data,$key)
{
    $keyHash = md5($key);
    $key = substr($keyHash, 0,   mcrypt_get_key_size(self::$cipher, self::$mode) );
    $iv  = substr($keyHash, 0, mcrypt_get_block_size(self::$cipher, self::$mode) );

    $data = mcrypt_encrypt(self::$cipher, $key, $data, self::$mode, $iv);
    return base64_encode($data);
}

public static function decrypt($data,$key)
{
    $keyHash = md5($key);
    $key = substr($keyHash, 0,   mcrypt_get_key_size(self::$cipher, self::$mode) );
    $iv  = substr($keyHash, 0, mcrypt_get_block_size(self::$cipher, self::$mode) );

    $data = base64_decode($data);
    return mcrypt_decrypt(self::$cipher, $key, $data, self::$mode, $iv);
}
}
```

Vou completar para responder no cometario: no caso dos base de dados, das sessaos, e muito dificil saber onde sao os dados. E de verdade, não importa. Se uma pessoa pode fazer uma injecçao SQL, ela não precisa saber "exatamente onde" são os dados: ela precisa saber como ler os dados. E suficiente.
Então, achar que tudo ta certo porque os dados não no servidor e uma brincadeira: o que precisa e proteger o aceso, então, evitar "dar a chave da casa". A dificuldade e que o visitante... deve ter a chave para acessar! Significa que a chave vai estar no navegador.

O problema maior e a ligaçao entre a chave e os dados e a pergunta principal e "como fazer para evitar a copia da chave e, pior, como evitar que uma pessao entende o sistema da chave para fazer uma copia igual o que parace igual".

Analisar os Cookie no seu navegador permite facilmente ver que tem que não são protegidos: vc vai var o seu id por exemplo. Com um software tipo https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=fr vc pode modificar os cookie.

Isso significa que precisa modificar o cookie para evitar a modificaçao, colocar mas que o Id, criar uma ligaçao entre os dados do cookie. 
O objetivo jamais vai ser de colocar todas as info no cookie: o objetivo esta de impedir a modificaço do cookie e ter a capacidade, do lado do servidor, saber que a chave esta coreta. Depois, com uma chave coreta, ler os dados da BDD é facil.

Comment: Os dados da sessão são guardados no servidor. O cookie geralmente só contém um id de sessão para poder recuperar esses dados na outra ponta.

Comment: Não estou contestando que existam medidas adicionais de [segurança contra *session hijacking*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33740), só quis esclarecer que os dados de sessão geralmente não ficam guardados em cookies (o autor da pergunta parecia confuso quanto a isso). E, para constar, o -1 na sua resposta não é meu.