# Trabalhar com session é seguro?

Tags: php, session

Exemplo, se eu criar uma sessão

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome; #valor pegado anteriormente.
```

O usuário final pode ver e(ou) editar os dados contidos nela?

Comment: Sua pergunta é respondida aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38920/o-que-guardar-em-uma-sess%C3%A3o-de-login/38970#38970

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Falando sobre a API nativa do PHP, os dados da sessão ficam em um arquivo do lado do servidor, que geralmente fica em uma pasta fora, `public_html` ou `www`, e isto torna o acesso para o usuário final impossível.

No entanto, quem desenvolve o sistema pode sim acabar expondo os dados de alguma maneira, então podemos dizer que depende da maneira que foi programado.

### Expondo os dados da pasta

Às vezes configuramos as pasta de sessão em outro local, que é acessível publicamente:

```
session_save_path('/etc/www/sessions');
```

Você também pode acidentalmente expor os dados de `$_SESSION`, mas é provável que os dados expostos sejam do próprio usuário, no entanto, é possível compartilhar a sessão, e isto pode ser uma dor de cabeça.

Concluindo, sessões no PHP não são "inseguras", a maneira que você programa é que pode lhe expor.

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado, Guilherme :)

Answer (score 7):

As variáveis de sessão no PHP são cookies server-side, ou seja, são cookies salvos no servidor.

Usuários comuns sem acesso administrativo ao servidor não tem acesso aos arquivos, desde que estejam num diretório privado e, por padrão, o PHP salva os cookies num diretório privado.

Contudo, é preciso ter cuidado onde os cookies são salvos no servidor pois o PHP permite configurar o local dos cookies até mesmo em tempo de execução:

Se o programador for um jumento, definirá os cookies numa pasta de acesso público:

```
session_save_path('/var/www/website.foo/public/sessions');
```

Com isso, deixa tudo vulnerável.

Mas essa é uma situação muito difícil de acontecer, mesmo para "jumentos".

Uma precaução mais importante é, quando salvar dados sensíveis em variáveis de sessão, como login e senha, sempre codifique os dados pois pode existir um administrador malicioso com acesso ao servidor ou mesmo um hacker pode ter acesso físico aos arquivos.

**Sequestro de sessões**

As variáveis de sessão podem ser sequestradas. Isso é chamado de *session hijacking*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

**Como é possível sequestrar o session_id do PHP?**

Não é muito difícil. Basta ter acesso ao computador de uma pessoa que esteja com a sessão aberta.

Apesar dos dados das variáveis de sessão serem gravados no servidor, as variáveis de sessão também precisam de um cookie client-side. Nesse cookie contém o session_id, ou, o ID da sessão. Esse ID é o que identifica qual é o cookie no servidor.

Aí está a jogada! Se vc tem o ID, consegue obter os dados do servidor referente ao mesmo.

Então basta transportar o cookie client-side que contém o ID de sessão para outro computador. Com isso, estará, por exemplo, logado no seu computador como se fosse outra pessoa.

**Como evitar o sequestro?**

Uma técnica básica para evitar o sequestro de sessões é gerar um novo ID de sessão periodicamente. Recomenda-se gerar um novo ID a cada 5 minutos.

Alguns acham exagero e definem como 1 hora ou mais. Porém, uma hora é mais que o suficiente para roubar um session id. Por isso, defina um período de tempo mais curto.

No PHP existe a função `session_regenerate_id()`, que pode ser usada para gerar novos IDs de sessão. http://php.net/session_regenerate_id

**Dedo duro**

No PHP, há uma diretiva de configuração do ambiente chamada **session.use-trans-sid**. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid

Essa diretiva, quando ativada, transporta o ID da sessão de forma transparente em requisições `$_GET` e `$_POST` de forma automática.

Recomenda-se que desative essa opção pois apenas facilita que um hacker obtenha o session id de alguém, mesmo sem ter acesso físico ao computador da vítima.

Por quê o PHP possui essa configuração "nociva"? 
O motivo é que é uma configuração de tempos obscuros, dos primórdios da internet onde tínhamos muitos problemas para lidar com cookies nos browsers da época entre 1996 ~ 2003. Atualmente não há necessidade em se preocupar com isso.

**Session name**

Por definição padrão, o nome do parâmetro que contém o ID de sessão no cookie client-side é `PHPSESSID`.

É recomendável que modifique para outro nome que não dê pistas sobre qual tecnologia utiliza no servidor. Isso dificulta o trabalho de um hacker em obter informações de um servidor no qual deseja atacar ou explorar vulnerabilidades.

No PHP, temos a função `session_name()`, onde é possível definir um nome customizado.

Defina como *ASPSESSIONID*, por exemplo. Com isso, um hacker pensará que o site utiliza *ASP* e ficará perdendo tempo procurando vulnerabilidades do *ASP* ao invés do *PHP*.

Um hacker mais experiente pode perceber isso verificando outros dados no cabeçalho de requisções ao servidor. Por exemplo, o Apache envia dados que podem expor que o servidor utiliza Apache e PHP. Portanto, procure também como omitir tais dados.

Para servidor Apache, na diretiva  `<Directory>` do `<Virtualhost>`, adicione a linha `php_value expose_php Off`.

Dependendo das configurações do servidor, isso só é permitido alterar no php.ini.

Há diversos outros detalhes que podem expor informações do servidor. Caso queira saber mais, pesquise sobre o assunto.

Algumas palavras-chave para pesquisar:

```
hide apache server info
php expose off
hide php info
```

Comment: +1 pelos detalhes adicionais sobre sequestro. Mas o PHP não usa exatamente "cookies no servidor", que eu saiba. Pode usar sim arquivos em disco (não sei como ele serializa), BD ou mesmo a memória RAM. Depende de como o PHP está configurado.

Comment: O termo "cookie server side" é um termo popular. Obviamente que não são cookies como num browser client-side. Mas podemos definir/apelidar os arquivos de variáveis de sessão do php como cookies também. Por isso o termo "cookie server side".

Comment: Eu nunca tinha ouvido isso, pelo visto tô por fora :P

Comment: é um termo bem antigo.. pensei que todo programador php soubesse.