# Sessions de diferentes sistemas no mesmo servidor

Tags: php, session

### Cenário (exemplo)

Tenho 2 sistemas:

- Sistema Padaria
- Sistema Posto

---

### Detalhes

- O **banco de dados é separado**, então cada sistema com seus usuários e senhas.
- Há **"usuário comum"** entre os 2 (ex.: joão.silva)

---

### Problemas

Se eu não usar um `session_name()` diferente para cada sistema, se estou logado com o "joao.silva" no sistema padaria, e entra no sistema posto, ele irá entrar direto, como se tivesse autenticado.

---

### Dúvidas

- Quando usar o `session_name()`?
- Quando usar o `session_id()`?
- Qual o mais `seguro`?
- Algo mais importante nesse contexto?

---

*PS.: Agradeço links bons para estudo. Favor evitar pesquisados no Google sem ao menos conferir se o conteúdo é completo e utilizado atualmente.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente deixe-me explicar o principal, as sessões são globais, se estão no mesmo servidor e dominio então elas podem ser acessadas por diferentes aplicações.

No entanto é possível limitar as pastas que podem acessar o cookie da sessão ajustando o `session_set_cookie_params`, algo como:

```
 setcookie(time() + 3600, '/sistema_a/'); //Somente acessivel na pasta sistema_a
 session_start();
```

Mas é claro que esse controle é somente no cookie, ainda é possivel obter os valores trocando se usar o mesmo `session_id`.

Alguns detalhes:

- `session_name` vai pegar apenas a sessão chamada no momento
- você não pode ler duas sessões ao mesmo tempo, dá até pra fazer umas *manobras* no código mas não vai funcionar tão bem ou de maneira tão pratica.
- `session_regenerate_id` não garante uma segurança geral, mas um lugar que realmente ela pode ser útil é contra sequestros de sessões, o que não tem haver com seu problema

### Como a sessão funciona?

Ao usar `session_start` será criado um cookie te terá um código aleatório que irá se referir a um arquivo na pasta `/tmp` (ou `c:\caminho\para\o\php\temp` ou `c:\window\temp` em caso de Windows Server), ou seja, os dados ficam no back-end, não tem como alguém rouba-los a não ser que você como desenvolvedor tenha feito algo muito errado, uma explicação sobre exposição dos dados no back-end:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99377/3635

---

Mas voltando a falar das suas aplicações, se você for o criador de ambas ou no minimo entender a estrutura de ambas das sessões, o que você pode fazer é checar se já está não esta logado e tentar importar os dados passando eles para o formato do desejado, por exemplo:

- Sistema A, está com `session_name` chamado `SYSTEM_A` e o formato da sessão:

  ```
  array(
     'sys_a' => array(
           'idUser' => '<id do usuario>',
           'name' => '<nome do usuario>',
           'update' => <ultima requisição HTTP atualiza esta chave>
     )
  )
  ```
- Sistema B, está com `session_name` chamado `SISTEM_B` e o formato da sessão:

  ```
  array(
     'sys_b' => array(
           'id' => '<id do usuario>',
           'user' => '<nome do usuario>',
           'lastactive' => <ultima requisição HTTP atualiza esta chave>
     )
  )
  ```

São semelhante, mas não são iguais, então supondo que você esteja logado no **sistema A** e vai abrir o **sistema B**, você poderia criar um arquivo e incluir no topo de todos chamado `sync_from_sis_a.php`, assim:

```
<?php

require_once 'sync_from_sis_a.php';
```

O conteúdo de `sync_from_sis_a.php` seria:

```
<?php
session_name('SYSTEM_A');
session_start();

//Verifica se NÃO esta logado no B e se ESTA logado no A
if (empty($_SESSION['sys_b']['id']) && isset($_SESSION['sys_a']['idUser'])) {
   $id = $_SESSION['sys_a']['idUser'];
   $nome = $_SESSION['sys_a']['name'];

   session_write_close(); //Finaliza o handle

   session_name('SYSTEM_B'); //Agora no sistema B
   session_start();

   //Copia os dados da sessão anterior para a sessão do sistema B
   $_SESSION['sys_b']['id'] = $id;
   $_SESSION['sys_b']['user'] = $nome;
   $_SESSION['sys_b']['lastactive'] = time();
}
```

Se não estiver logado no sistema A então irá abrir o sistema B normalmente pedindo o login.

O mesmo deverá ser feito no sistema A, checar se já esta logado no proprio, então se não tiver checar se esta logado no B, então crie um arquivo chamado `sync_from_sis_b.php` e incluir no topo de todos arquivos do **sistema A**, o arquivo deve ser assim:

```
<?php
session_name('SYSTEM_B');
session_start();

//Verifica se NÃO esta logado no A e se ESTA logado no B
if (empty($_SESSION['sys_a']['idUser']) && isset($_SESSION['sys_b']['id'])) {
   $id = $_SESSION['sys_b']['id'];
   $nome = $_SESSION['sys_b']['user'];

   session_write_close(); //Finaliza o handle

   session_name('SYSTEM_A'); //Agora no sistema A
   session_start();

   //Copia os dados da sessão anterior para a sessão do sistema B
   $_SESSION['sys_a']['idUser'] = $id;
   $_SESSION['sys_a']['name'] = $nome;
   $_SESSION['sys_b']['update'] = time();
}
```

**Nota:** tudo isso acima explicado é hipotético, não tem como sabermos o funcionamento dos seus sistemas, pode ser que use sessão criptografada ou que tenha um estrutura complexa, não existe maneira mágica de sincronizar 2 sistemas diferentes, ainda mais se não foi você quem fez, a unica solução é você entender ambos sistemas ou que eles forneçam APIs para facilitar este tipo de operação.

---

### Respondendo as perguntas

> Quando usar o session_name() ?
>
> Quando usar o session_id() ?
>
> Qual o mais seguro ?

Em resumo `session_name` mesmo que você não defina é gerado assim, como o `session_id`, nenhum deles tem haver com segurança, cada um representa isto no COOKIE enviado no HTTP:

```
Set-Cookie: <NOME DA SESSÃO>=<ID DA SESSÃO>
```

Então se definir criar no seu PHP assim:

```
<?php
session_name('foo');
session_id('baz');
session_start();

echo 'Hello world!';
```

No HTTP a resposta vai provavelmente ser semelhante a isto:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 21:06:18 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Set-Cookie: foo=baz; path=/

Hello world!
```

Então `session_name` será o nome do cookie e na pasta `./tmp` será gerado um arquivo com o nome `c:/php/temp/sess_baz`, que é o mesmo nome do ID.

Comment: Guilherme, entendi perfeitamente toda sua explicação, e já agradeço demais toda atenção ! A única coisa que me ficou "vago" no entendimento, é onde o session_id() e session_regenerate_id() entrariam no código, para ser feita a "validação" dele nas páginas, ou se eu estou entendendo algo errado...

Comment: @RaoniBZ regenerate ID troca o valor de `<ID DA SESSÃO>` (no exemplo da resposta) por um valor randomico. É util para evitar sequestros (o que não tem haver com o problema), se fizer isto a todo momento

Comment: Mas o `session_id`, eu não tenho que validá-lo para saber que aquela session é realmente do usuário ? Ou só é utilizado para o cookie ?

Comment: @RaoniBZ não o session_id é usado pelo COOKIE para conseguir saber qual arquivo da TMP ou representa, como expliquei na resposta na parte que falo "Como a sessão funciona?"

Comment: Ah entendi ! Então realmente o que irá separar as sessions dos 2 sistemas será a session_name ! o session_id e session_regenerate_id seriam uma segurança a mais caso capturem a sessão, correto ?

Comment: @RaoniBZ na verdade o session_id que separa, o session_name é para associar ao cookie, o session_regenerate é só pra gerar um novo ID (ele irá copiar os dados de uma sessão para a outra e creio que o GC irá remover o antigo)

Comment: Mas se o session_id é automático, e separa as sessions, então não poderia acontecer dos 2 sistemas logarem caso o usuário estiver com sessão aberta em um sistema só.

Comment: @RBZ ambos, name ou id, podem ser automaticos, como podem ser criados por você, isso é relativo, agora o que importa saber é que name é o que associa ao cookie e id é o valor que associa ao arquivo no back-end na pasta TMP. Não

Comment: Se eu fosse usar então o session_id para validação de sessão, eu poderia por exemplo usar o id_usuario e usuario para gerar uma chave md5 como o session_id, e validar usando session_id === md5($uid.$uname), basicamente assim ?

Comment: @RBZ Não faça isso por favor!!, isso é complicado e provavelmente instavel, use um valor dentro de `$_SESSION['minhachave'] = array(token=>....)` com hashs e compare depois `$_SESSION['minhachave'][token] === outra origem`

Comment: Opa tranquilo !! rs Hoje, atualmente, a forma mais utilizada qual é ? Tem como fazer uma estilo os "token" ?

Comment: O maior problema é que a documentação do php nessa parte é muito fraca, e não se encontra algo bem detalhado, bem explicado do porque e como usar as sessions da melhor forma, e alguns até usando o session_id dessa forma que falei...

Comment: @RBZ não é problema na documentação do PHP, sessão não tem foco exclusivo em segurança, o uso de session é muito variado, existem casos que nem tem sentido aplicar segurança, ou seja a documentação não tem porque explicar de usos especificos, já que o foco é variado. O mais usado é relativo, cada um faz de uma forma, todavia algo sem sessão que usam bastante é o JWt, que é um serviço 3rdparty, se quiser entender o JWt veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155013/3635 - mas é porque usam muito que vc deve usar, vai da sua necessidade.

Comment: Caramba, é um negócio tão simples que é daqueles negócios que fica difícil acreditar que é "só isso" entende !? kkkk Mas entendi perfeitamente, você chegou basicamente onde eu queria chegar, nos TOKEN, para poder fazer um WS junto a um APP. Guilherme muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelo seu tempo ! Agradecido demais !

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente uma sessão eh uma variável superglobal em forma de array, onde você armazena dados por um determinado tempo.

De acordo com a [documentacao oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-id.php) para `session_id()`:

> session_id() é usado para obter ou definir o id de sessão para a
>   sessão atual.

E para `session_name()`

> session_name — Obtém e/ou define o nome da sessão atual

A diferença das duas esta em seu proposito e um pouco em seu funcionamento, `session_id` é definido uma vez antes de iniciar a sessão, e você NÃO vai precisar chamar o método todas as vezes que precisar usar um dado da sessão, boa parte da segurança da sessão vem da função `session_regenerate_id`, e chamando este método, você ira gerar uma nova identificação para sessão sem perder os dados, porem não vai conseguir identificar naturalmente qual é cada sessão, isso é bem útil para sessões abertas por um tempo longo, pois mesmo que a identificação seja capturada sua identificação sera modificada durante o uso.

Para identificar múltiplas sessões no mesmo servidor, o mais viável é a utilização de um nome para sessão, pois esse nome não vai interferir no seu identificador e você pode chamar em qualquer parte qualquer uma das sessões abertas pre-definidas e ainda sim permanecer regerando os identificadores para a sessão.

Referencias:

[Uso basico](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.examples.basic.php)

[Session ID](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-id.php)

[Session Regenerate ID](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

[Session Name](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-name.php)

Comment: Então a sequência para gerar com o nome e id seria: 1. session_name() 2. session_id() 3. session_start() correto ?

Comment: O `session_id()` eu posso usar como `id` qualquer coisa (geralmente criptografada) correto !? Mas o que geralmente é usado ? Nome do usuário ? Como que ele vai validar a session ? Com os dados que tiver na variável global ?